# Click the ios7 web app map link, it opens the Google maps instead of default map app

Tags: mobile, maps, ios7

I have a mobile website/app that I created, and the map links opened the local map app before the IOS 7 upgrade. Now when I save the mobile site to the home screen, and click on the map link it opens up in Google Maps instead of the local Apple map app.

This is the code I am currently using:

`<a href="http://maps.apple.com/?q=cupertino">`

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is it opening in the Google Maps *app* or *website*?  If it's opening in the google maps *app*, it could be an issue with your default maps app (I honestly don't know)

Otherwise, that should work.

I would also maybe verify that you are not looking at a cached copy.

..also, is this Safari (default) or Chrome?